Pinned program disappears from taskbar in Windows 11, why?
In Window 11, when I launch this program (far.exe in  my case), its icon appears on the taskbar. Right-click on this icon shows "unpin from Taskbar", so I  deduce it was pinned. Next, I pin it again. However,
when I close this program's window, the icon (now pinned?) disappears from the taskbar. How  can I make the icon to stick on the taskbar even after I close the program, for me to launch this program with this icon.
Or actually, maybe Microsoft does this by design to force  us to use the start menu?
In Windows 10 it used to be possible to really pin programs to the taskbar. Now in the so much "improved" Windows 11  does this no longer work?

"maybe Microsoft does this by design to force us to use the start menu?" - This is not happening. Something is happening, and it could be a design limitation of the application itself and even an incompatibility with Windows 11.  I assume it works fine on Windows 10? There are significant differences between Windows 10 and Windows 11 when it comes to the Start Menu.

I've seen this happen to a program after an update. The program changes, so technically, the old program that was pinned does not exist anymore, but when you start the new program, it matches the pinned status, so it appears to be pinned, but it really is not. Just unpin an pin to fix the issue.

@LPChip  Thank you! No this does not work. I  run the(updated) program  and its icon appears on the taskbar. I say Unpin from taskbar from the right-click munu on this icon; nothing changes. I close the program's window and the icon disappears from the taskbar. No matter how many times I repeat this cycle. Still no icon on the taskbar, even after reboot.

After the unpin, you pin it again, right?

@PChip  Yes, I edited the question to clarify that I unpin it and then pin  it again, and so many times. No effect.

If you go to the program location, right-click drag it into the same folder, choose "Create shortcut here", agree to create the shortcut on the desktop when it moans, right-click the shortcut on the desktop, choose "Show more options" -> "Pin to Taskbar", does it perform as you wanted? If you're feeling brave, you can then delete the desktop shortcut. If it works, let me know and I'll write it as an answer for you.

@Morton Thank you!  I did  not try  the trick with shortcut. What worked for me, fist I pinned it to Start and then in the Start window, right-click on it, Pin to Taskbar. I think it is essentially the same as the shortcut trick.

@Morton Please convert your comment into an answer.

You can:

go to the program location
right-click drag it into the same folder
choose "Create shortcut here"
agree to create the shortcut on the desktop when it moans
right-click the shortcut on the desktop
choose "Show more options" -> "Pin to Taskbar".

That way gives you an opportunity to modify the shortcut properties.
